# Moodle LMS v3.9 - Course Completion not firing after activity completion

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I have a Moodle LMS Self-Hosted solution which uses version v3.9

A course completion has been set to occur when an activity has completed. However, when I this occurs, the activity completion is recorded, but the course isn't checked with "Course Completed". It appears to be recording in the "course_completions" table but only inserts fields (id, userid, course, timestarted, reaggregate).

As a test, I adjusted the "Course Completion" in to be solely based upon "Manual Completion by Others", so I could just get it to record the completion.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

I would have expected when the activity was marked as completed or my as admin marked the course as complete, it would have set the course as complete and show a "check box" on the report screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running cron?

Go to Site administration > Server > Tasks > Scheduled tasks and check if '*Calculate regular completion data*' has been run recently

https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Course_completion_FAQ#Students_have_completed_the_criteria_but_the_report_does_not_show_it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the CRON stopped running.
Once I re-set it up, the course completion worked as expected.